# Python - Suds. How to edit the namespaces of SOAP-ENV:Envelope

Tags: python, namespaces, suds

I am creating a request to consume a Web Service using SUDS (4.0) in Django.
However Suds is not putting the right namespaces.

The Soap Envelope I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://factura360.com/invoice_webservice" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ns2:LoginObject>
            <soapusername>USER</soapusername>
            <soappassword>PASSWORD</soappassword>
        </ns2:LoginObject>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:generate_invoice>
            <document xsi:type="xsd:string">
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cfdi:Comprobante></cfdi:Comprobante>
            </document>
            <documenttype xsi:type="xsd:int">0</documenttype>
            <filetype xsi:type="xsd:int">1</filetype>
            <cer xsi:nil="true"></cer><key xsi:nil="true">
            </key><password xsi:type="xsd:string">PASSWORD</password>
        </ns1:generate_invoice>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What the SOAP Envelope should be:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://factura360.com/invoice_webservice" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ns2="namespace" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"> 
    <SOAP-ENV:Header>
           <ns2:LoginObject> 
               <soapusername>USER</soapusername> 
               <soappassword>PASSWORD</soappassword> 
           </ns2:LoginObject>
    </SOAP-ENV:Header> 
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:generate_invoice> 
            <document xsi:type="xsd:string"> 
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><cfdi:Comprobante>    </cfdi:Comprobante>
           </document>
           <documenttype xsi:type="xsd:int">0</documenttype> 
           <filetype xsi:type="xsd:int">1</filetype>
           <cer xsi:nil="true"></cer> 
           <key xsi:nil="true"></key>
           <password xsi:type="xsd:string">PASSWORD</password> 
        </ns1:generate_invoice> 
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So, according to the desired SOAP Envelope, there should be no 'xmlns:ns0', no 'xmlns:ns3', there should be xmlns:xsd with value 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' and 'xmlns:ns2' should have  a value of 'namespace'.

My actual function to edit the Envelope is this one:

```
class CorrectNamespace(MessagePlugin):
    def marshalled(self, context):
        soap_env_parent = context.envelope
        soap_env_parent.set('xmlns:xsd', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema')
        soap_env_parent.unset('xmlns:ns0')
        soap_env_parent.unset('xmlns:ns3')
        soap_env_parent.unset('xmlns:ns2')
        soap_env_parent.set('xmlns:ns2', 'namespace')

factura_client = Client(settings.FACTURA360_URL, plugins=[CorrectNamespace()])

#Setting the Login Object
lg_element = Element('ns2:LoginObject')
soapuser_element = Element('soapusername').setText(settings.FACTURA360_USER)
soappass_element = Element('soappassword').setText(settings.FACTURA360_PASS)
lg_element.append(soapuser_element)
lg_element.append(soappass_element)
factura_client.set_options(soapheaders=lg_element)

#The call to the webservice
invoice = factura_client.service.\
    generate_invoice(document, document_type, filetype,
                     cer, key, settings.FACTURA360_INVOICEPASSWORD)
```

Unfortunately, my plugin function is adding 'xmlns:xsd' and 'xmlns:ns2', but it is not deleting the others.

Here is the resulting Envelope with the plugin function:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope 
    xmlns:ns3="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:ns1="http://factura360.com/invoice_webservice" 
    xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
    SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:ns2="namespace">
```

How do I delete the other namespaces?

Comment: Try the suds-jurko package and see if the issue is still there.

Comment: I think there is no real problem here just an aesthetic one, right? The namespace names (e.g. "ns3") are not important as long as they are used consistently. Having extra namespaces is not a problem.

Comment: I have tried suds-jurko with the same results.
@FelixSchwarz It's not just extra namespaces, someones are modified

Answer (score -1):

```
class CorrectNamespace(MessagePlugin):
    def marshalled(self, context):
        del context.envelope.nsprefixes['ns3']
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.